# apply template in xslt is provided within nodes

Tags: xslt

my input xml looks like this .
..please help its my first xslt code..and struggling with it....

input xml ,output xml and xslt pasted here

Regards,
John

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZGOFBOM>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>1</TABNAM>
         <MANDT>020</MANDT>
         <DOCNUM>2</DOCNUM>
         <DOCREL>5</DOCREL>
         <STATUS>30</STATUS>
         <DIRECT>1</DIRECT>
         <OUTMOD>2</OUTMOD>
         <IDOCTYP>tyy</IDOCTYP>
         <CIMTYP>ZGOFBOM-NAMITA</CIMTYP>
         <MESTYP>iii</MESTYP>
         <SNDPOR>kkk</SNDPOR>
         <SNDPRT>ll</SNDPRT>
         <SNDPRN>ooo</SNDPRN>
         <RCVPOR>pp</RCVPOR>
         <RCVPRT>lll</RCVPRT>
         <RCVPRN>nnn</RCVPRN>
         <CREDAT>mmm</CREDAT>
         <CRETIM>mm</CRETIM>
         <SERIAL>nn</SERIAL>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1STZUM SEGMENT="1">
         <MSGFN>004</MSGFN>
         <STLTY>M</STLTY>
         <STLNR>00953866</STLNR>
         <STLAN>1</STLAN>
         <EXSTL>1.000</EXSTL>
         <STLDT>20181116</STLDT>
         <STLTM>130857</STLTM>
         <Z1STKH1 SEGMENT="1">
         <ZZBOM>1</ZZBOM>
         </Z1STKH1
         <E1MASTM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>004</MSGFN>
            <MATNR>SFP-10G-SR=</MATNR>
            <WERKS>US02</WERKS>
            <STLAN>1</STLAN>
            <STLNR>00953866</STLNR>
            <STLAL>01</STLAL>
            <LOSVN>0.000</LOSVN>
            <LOSBS>0.000</LOSBS>
         </E1MASTM>
         <E1STKOM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>004</MSGFN>
            <STLAL>01</STLAL>
            <DATUV>20181116</DATUV>
            <BMEIN>EA</BMEIN>
            <BMENG>000000000000000</BMENG>
            <STLST>01</STLST>
            <BMENG_C>1.000</BMENG_C>
         </E1STKOM>
         <E1STPOM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>004</MSGFN>
            <STLKN>00000001</STLKN>
            <DATUV>20181116</DATUV>
            <IDNRK>11-2362-01</IDNRK>
            <POSTP>L</POSTP>
            <POSNR>0010</POSNR>
            <MEINS>EA</MEINS>
            <MENGE>000000000000000</MENGE>
            <AUSCH>0.00</AUSCH>
            <AVOAU>0.00</AVOAU>
            <SANFE>X</SANFE>
            <SANKA>X</SANKA>
            <NLFZT>0</NLFZT>
            <EWAHR>0</EWAHR>
            <LIFZT>0</LIFZT>
            <PREIS>0.00</PREIS>
            <PEINH>0</PEINH>
            <ROANZ>0.000</ROANZ>
            <ROMS1>0.000</ROMS1>
            <ROMS2>0.000</ROMS2>
            <ROMS3>0.000</ROMS3>
            <ROMEN>22.000</ROMEN>
            <OBJTY>1</OBJTY>
            <WEBAZ>0</WEBAZ>
            <CSSTR>0.00</CSSTR>
            <KNOBJ>000000000000000000</KNOBJ>
            <ALPRF>00</ALPRF>
            <CLSZU>00000000</CLSZU>
            <NLFZV>0</NLFZV>
            <MENGE_C>22.000</MENGE_C>
            <ROMEN_C>0.000</ROMEN_C>
         </E1STPOM>
         <E1STPOM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>004</MSGFN>
            <STLKN>00000002</STLKN>
            <DATUV>20181116</DATUV>
            <IDNRK>78-19144-01</IDNRK>
            <POSTP>L</POSTP>
            <POSNR>0020</POSNR>
            <MEINS>EA</MEINS>
            <MENGE>000000000000000</MENGE>
            <AUSCH>0.00</AUSCH>
            <AVOAU>0.00</AVOAU>
            <SANFE>X</SANFE>
            <SANKA>X</SANKA>
            <NLFZT>0</NLFZT>
            <EWAHR>0</EWAHR>
            <LIFZT>0</LIFZT>
            <PREIS>0.00</PREIS>
            <PEINH>0</PEINH>
            <ROANZ>0.000</ROANZ>
            <ROMS1>0.000</ROMS1>
            <ROMS2>0.000</ROMS2>
            <ROMS3>0.000</ROMS3>
            <ROMEN>44.000</ROMEN>
            <OBJTY>1</OBJTY>
            <WEBAZ>0</WEBAZ>
            <CSSTR>0.00</CSSTR>
            <KNOBJ>000000000000000000</KNOBJ>
            <ALPRF>00</ALPRF>
            <CLSZU>00000000</CLSZU>
            <NLFZV>0</NLFZV>
            <MENGE_C>44.000</MENGE_C>
            <ROMEN_C>0.000</ROMEN_C>
         </E1STPOM>
         <E1STPOM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>004</MSGFN>
            <STLKN>00000003</STLKN>
            <DATUV>20181116</DATUV>
            <IDNRK>10-2415-03</IDNRK>
            <POSTP>L</POSTP>
            <POSNR>0030</POSNR>
            <MEINS>EA</MEINS>
            <MENGE>000000000000000</MENGE>
            <AUSCH>0.00</AUSCH>
            <AVOAU>0.00</AVOAU>
            <SANFE>X</SANFE>
            <SANKA>X</SANKA>
            <NLFZT>0</NLFZT>
            <EWAHR>0</EWAHR>
            <LIFZT>0</LIFZT>
            <PREIS>0.00</PREIS>
            <PEINH>0</PEINH>
            <ROANZ>0.000</ROANZ>
            <ROMS1>0.000</ROMS1>
            <ROMS2>0.000</ROMS2>
            <ROMS3>0.000</ROMS3>
            <ROMEN>88.000</ROMEN>
            <OBJTY>1</OBJTY>
            <WEBAZ>0</WEBAZ>
            <CSSTR>0.00</CSSTR>
            <KNOBJ>000000000000000000</KNOBJ>
            <ALPRF>00</ALPRF>
            <CLSZU>00000000</CLSZU>
            <NLFZV>0</NLFZV>
            <MENGE_C>88.000</MENGE_C>
            <ROMEN_C>0.000</ROMEN_C>
         </E1STPOM>
         <E1STPOM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>004</MSGFN>
            <STLKN>00000004</STLKN>
            <DATUV>20181116</DATUV>
            <IDNRK>11-2362-01</IDNRK>
            <POSTP>L</POSTP>
            <POSNR>0040</POSNR>
            <MEINS>EA</MEINS>
            <MENGE>000000000000000</MENGE>
            <AUSCH>0.00</AUSCH>
            <AVOAU>0.00</AVOAU>
            <SANFE>X</SANFE>
            <SANKA>X</SANKA>
            <NLFZT>0</NLFZT>
            <EWAHR>0</EWAHR>
            <LIFZT>0</LIFZT>
            <PREIS>0.00</PREIS>
            <PEINH>0</PEINH>
            <ROANZ>0.000</ROANZ>
            <ROMS1>0.000</ROMS1>
            <ROMS2>0.000</ROMS2>
            <ROMS3>0.000</ROMS3>
            <ROMEN>2.000</ROMEN>
            <OBJTY>1</OBJTY>
            <WEBAZ>0</WEBAZ>
            <CSSTR>0.00</CSSTR>
            <KNOBJ>000000000000000000</KNOBJ>
            <ALPRF>00</ALPRF>
            <CLSZU>00000000</CLSZU>
            <NLFZV>0</NLFZV>
            <MENGE_C>2.000</MENGE_C>
            <ROMEN_C>0.000</ROMEN_C>
         </E1STPOM>
      </E1STZUM>
   </IDOC>
</ZGOFBOM>
```

---

output xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <Transaction>
        <Plant></Plant>
        <TransType></TransType>
        <SAPIDocNumber></SAPIDocNumber>
        <BOMName></BOMName>
        <MaterialGroup/>
        <ChangeNumber/>
        <Customer_Revision>ZGOFBOM</Customer_Revision>
        <Version>JOHN</Version>
        <AlternativeBOM>01</AlternativeBOM>
        <Status>01</Status>
        <BomUsage/>
        <ValidFrom>20181116</ValidFrom>
        <Components>
            <Component>
                <ComponentName></ComponentName>
                <ItemNumber></ItemNumber>
                <Quantity>000000000000000</Quantity>
                <ChangeNumber/>
                <ItemID>00000001</ItemID>
                <ItemRev>000000000000000</ItemRev>
                <OptionalFlag>000000000000000</OptionalFlag>
                <AlternateGroup/>
                <ItemCategory>L</ItemCategory>
                <CRDs>
                    <CRDName>000000000000000</CRDName>
                    <Side>000000000000000</Side>
                </CRDs>
            </Component>
        </Components>
    </Transaction>
</Envelope>
```

#

to get output xml i have applied xslt..

one thing i dont know is how to split this

```
 <CIMTYP>ZGOFBOM-JOHN</CIMTYP>
```

into

```
       <Customer_Revision>ZGOFBOM</Customer_Revision>
        <Version>JOHN</Version>
```

#####################################applied xslt as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <Envelope>
                <Transaction>
                    <Plant>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//E1MASTM/WERKS"/>
                    </Plant>
                    <TransType>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//EDI_DC40/IDOCTYP"/>
                    </TransType>
                    <SAPIDocNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//EDI_DC40/DOCNUM"/>
                    </SAPIDocNumber>


                    <xsl:apply-templates select = "//EDI_DC40/CIMTYP"/> 

                    <BOMName>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//E1STZUM/E1MASTM/MATNR"/>
                    </BOMName>
                    <MaterialGroup>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//E1STZUM/ZE1MASTM/MATKL"/>
                    </MaterialGroup>
                    <ChangeNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//E1STZUM/E1STKOM/AENNR"/>
                    </ChangeNumber>
                    <Customer_Revision>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//Z1STKH1/ZZPLREV"/>
                    </Customer_Revision>
                    <Version>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//Z1STKH1/ZZPLREV"/>
                    </Version>
                    <AlternativeBOM>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//E1STZUM/E1MASTM/STLAL"/>
                    </AlternativeBOM>
                    <Status>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//E1STZUM/E1STKOM/STLST"/>
                    </Status>
                    <BomUsage>
                         <xsl:value-of select = "//E1STZUM/Z1STKH1/ZZBOM"/>
                    </BomUsage>

                     <xsl:if test="//E1STZUM/Z1STKH1/ZZBOM ='1'">
                      <BomType>
                        <xsl:text>Fixed</xsl:text>
                       </BomType>
                     </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="//E1STZUM/Z1STKH1/ZZBOM ='5'">
                      <BomType>
                        <xsl:text>Super</xsl:text>
                       </BomType>
                     </xsl:if>
                    <ValidFrom>
                        <xsl:value-of select = "//E1STZUM/E1STKOM/DATUV"/>
                    </ValidFrom>
                    <Components>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//E1STZUM/E1STPOM">
                            <Component>
                                <ComponentName>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "IDNRK"/>
                                </ComponentName>
                                <ItemNumber>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "POSNR"/>
                                </ItemNumber>
                                <Quantity>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "MENGE"/>
                                </Quantity>
                                <ChangeNumber>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "AENNR"/>
                                </ChangeNumber>
                                <ItemID>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "STLKN"/>
                                </ItemID>
                                <ItemRev>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "MENGE"/>
                                </ItemRev>
                                <OptionalFlag>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "MENGE"/>
                                </OptionalFlag>
                                <AlternateGroup>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "ALPGR"/>
                                </AlternateGroup>
                                <ItemCategory>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "POSTP"/>
                                </ItemCategory>
                                <CRDs>
                                    <CRDName>
                                        <xsl:value-of select = "MENGE"/>
                                    </CRDName>
                                    <Side>
                                        <xsl:value-of select = "MENGE"/>
                                    </Side>
                                </CRDs>
                            </Component>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Components>

                </Transaction>
            </Envelope>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="//EDI_DC40/CIMTYP">">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="sep" select="' - '"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $sep)">
                <customer>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $sep)"/>
                </customer>
                <!-- recursive call -->
                <headRev>
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $sep)" />
                </headRev>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <revision>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                </revision>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

************************DID THIS***********************

```
 <xsl:variable name="show" select="//EDI_DC40/CIMTYP"/> 
                 <xsl:variable name="criteriaHyp" select="-"/>  
            <xsl:if test="contains($show, '-')">
            <customer>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($show, $criteriaHyp)"/>
            </customer>
            <headRev>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($show, $criteriaHyp)" />
            </headRev>

            </xsl:if>
```

Comment: The template matching "//EDI_DC40/CIMTYP" has a comment about making a recursive call, but if the value is only going to have a single separator in, then a recursive call is not necessary. Can the field actually have multiple separators?

Comment: Please tag XSLT questions as xslt 1.0 or xslt 2.0 (or even 3.0). All three versions are in common use, and if we give an answer for the wrong version then we're wasting your time and ours.

Comment: No Tim fields will only have one value...I don't understand why there is a compilation error

Comment: Sure Michael I will tag this

Comment: It's for xslt 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done

```
<xsl:template match="//EDI_DC40/CIMTYP">">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
```

But you don't supply a value for $text, and you don't need to. The element will be the context node, which you can refer to as ".". So it's simply:

```
        <xsl:when test="contains(., $sep)">
            <customer>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $sep)"/>
            </customer>
            <headRev>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., $sep)" />
            </headRev>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <revision>
                <xsl:value-of select=."/>
            </revision>
        </xsl:otherwise>
```

Comment: <xsl:variable name="show" select="//EDI_DC40/CIMTYP"/> 
     <xsl:variable name="criteriaHyp" select="-"/> 
            <xsl:if test="contains($show, '-')">
   <customer>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($show, $criteriaHyp)"/>
            </customer>
   <headRev>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($show, $criteriaHyp)" />
            </headRev>
   
   </xsl:if>